# Как имитировать рестарт python скрипта (проблема связана с selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium, cookie

Я захожу на один сайт через selenium, который каждый раз сохраняет мне в куки определенное значение (хэш, я не знаю из чего он состоит). Вот только если я сделаю webdriver.quit() и получу куки заново, то значение кук не поменяется, но если я перезапущу скрипт (ctrl+c и запущу заново), то значение куки изменится. Т.е в рантайме как бы я не очищал все (пробовал importlib.reload), значение всегда одинаковое, при перезапуске - куки меняется. Остальные значения куки кроме этого магического меняются и всегда новые, т.е при каждой новой инициализации драйвера профиль браузера абсолютно чистый. Пожалуйста, объясните эту магию, я не представляю как это можно загуглить даже

Comment: Попробуй driver.delete_all_cookies()

Comment: На сколько мне известно что-то может попасть еще и в кэш, но его через selenium не сбросить.

Comment: А есть вообще способы сбросить кэш? delete_all_cookie не помогло. Такое ощущение, что сайт использует для формирования переменной какое-то системное значение, которое браузер передает и которое меняется с каждым запуском скрипта